# Detect if a div has more than one line

Tags: html, css

How can I detect if a div has more than one line? I mean like this:

```
div :multiline {
   ...
}
```

I'd like to format the content regarding the number of lines (1 or more)

Comment: CSS has the pseudo-element `::first-line`, but that's the only line-based selector available in CSS, which has no true ability to create conditional checks or styling. How do you want to format the content?

Comment: This div would be an "alert" div, and I'd like to make `padding-left:0px` if it has only one line, otherwise `padding-left:5px`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to use Javascript/JQuery, you could check the height of the div and see if it is greater than it would be with only one line of text. Of course, this isn't very error-proof, but I wouldn't know another way.

Comment: @KissKoppány Not that I've seen.

Comment: I don't think so either. Searched around a bit more and found nothing JS-less.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't call this a solution so much as something that could potentially lead to a solution. I thought your question was interesting; so I decided to play around with CSS for a little bit.

[This is what I came up with.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/FDja7/3/)

It uses the current width of the internal `span` (given through `inline-block` display) to determine the indent width. We use `calc()` to make the indent `100%` minus the parent width of `200px` which has our final indent added to it (`30px`).

It works best if the single-line content does not get near the full width of the container.

Quick Notes:

1. I've noted some failure cases due to the single-line content getting near the full width of the container. (Distance from the full-width causing erroneous visuals varies between browsers, tested in Chrome 33, Firefox 25, and Internet Explorer 11)
2. It uses `calc()` ([list of support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc))
3. It uses `:before` pseudo class ([list of support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent))
4. It requires the use of an internal `inline-block` element to track content width.
5. It requires the parent element to have a known width.
6. This only covers indentation which is what OP States they are trying to achieve in the comments of their post.

**HTML Code:**

```
<h1>Success Cases</h1>
<p><span class="indent">Single line Single line</span></p>
<p><span class="indent">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</span></p>
<h1>Failure Cases</h1>
<p><span class="indent">Single line Single line Single 1</span></p>
<p><span class="indent">Single line Single line Single line</span></p>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
p {
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

p > .indent {
    display: inline-block;
}
p > .indent:before {
    background-color: red;
    content: "";
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 200px + 30px);
    height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I think your **demo** is not really intuitive for what the OP **really** wants (like the imaginary `:multiline` pseudo-class), could you edit the demo so that if the `div` contains only 1 single line, its background-color will be `green` and if it contains more than 1 line (multiline), its background-color should be `red`? In general case, we need many more style properties than just background-color.

Comment: This unfortunately only works for indentation which is what OP states they are trying to achieve in the comments of their original post. It doesn't detect multiline so much as use the width of the content to base the indentation width off of. I think a more general solution to actually detect if an element is multiline or not will only work in JavaScript. You could probably determine it server side and attach a multiline class, but it would fail if the user agent has the font size overridden, shrunk, or enlarged. In the cases you would like to achieve, I would recommend JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you would be able to manage this with CSS but you should be able to do this JQuery. I must admit that my JQuery isn't great and I am in the process of learning it, so do take it with a pinch of salt. You can use the height of the property to find the height of the div and add the necessary styles based on the height of the div.

```
$( "div" ).ready( 
  function test(event) {
  var heightOfDiv = $( document ).height();

   if (heightOfDiv > 15){
    $("div").css({
    backgroundColor: "green"
    });} 
}
);
```